# I have ajax response that I have checked in console of firefox.But I need to display that response as html table in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.category-link').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).data('hash');
  var value = href.substring(1);
  getresultCategory('ajax.php?Category='+value);
  });


   function getresultCategory(url){
    $.ajax({
   url:url,
    type:'GET',
    success:function(){ 
     alert('sucess');
  } 
 });
 }
});
</script>";
```

Here is the response I got in firefox console

```
<div id="data-result">
<table class='cat_table'>
<tr><td>WFM</td><td>Name</td><td>9</td><td>13</td><td>1</td><td>1</td>
<td>32</td></tr>
<tr><td>CCE</td><td>Name</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>5</td><td>2</td>
<td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>PM</td><td>Name</td><td>4</td><td>8</td><td>7</td><td>3</td>
<td>25</td></tr></table></div>
```

I want this response in my display as html table in php

Comment: Firstly, I'm assuming you mean 'display as a table in Javascript', otherwise you'd need to make another AJAX request, which is kind of pointless. Secondly, all you need to do is `append()` the HTML you receive back where you need it: http://api.jquery.com/append

Comment: I tried using append but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Put an element in your HTML to receive the response, for example:

```
<div id="myTable"></div>
```

Then modify the success function of your AJAX call to place the data from the call into the HTML element:

```
success:function(data){ // add a variable in the function 
     $('#myTable').html(data); // place the data in the HTML element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create one div tag to receive output of ajax response

```
<div id="datatabe"></div>
```

then modify your ajax response on ajax success

```
success:function(data){ // add a variable in the function 
 $('#datatabe').append(data); // place the data in the HTML element
```

}